# Flutter Error: Type 'required' not found. after SDK update to 2.10.0

Tags: flutter, dart

I have updated my SDK to 2.10.0, I have resolved all new conflics.(example: "required" instead of "@required") And after that when I wanted run my tests I had several errors with this. The compiler think "required" is a data type and not just the new version of "@required".

how to make the compiler understand that "required" is "@required" and not a data type ?

Comment: One quick thing to keep in mind is that.

Before null safety, it was `@required` ,after null safety is `required`

Answer (score -1):

You need to import either:

```
  package:flutter/cupertino.dart'
  package:flutter/material.dart'
  package:flutter/foundation.dart'
  package:flutter/widgets.dart'
```

Comment: I have always my error. 

Error: 'required' isn't a type.
Context: This isn't a type. const Required required = Required();

Comment: sorry is true, the newer dart version change the @required for required.